# Redis transforming keys into "backup"

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-ec2, redis

I deployed an AWS EC2 instance that runs my Redis Server. I'm connecting the Redis server to my node/express server and setting key values through the Redis npm package. When I set these keys in Redis, the key names are the same key names I input into the datastore (e.g key: "key1". Though, after five minutes or so, the keys change from "key1", "key2", to "backup1", "backup2" etc. I cannot find any resources in the documentation explaining why this happens or how to prevent it.
** Note: I looked into disabling the Redis persistence, but I was unable to prevent the keys from changing to "backup" regardless.

Comment: Does this happen locally with the same application? Or only on EC2?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Only on EC2